# jQuery Tablesorter won't work on JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, tablesorter

I have a simple page with a table and i want it to be sortable, so i got jquery and tablesorter. Heres my page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/base.css"/>
    <script src="/javascript/jquery-1.4.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabela").tableSorter();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>        
    <p>
        <label><h3>Lista de Personagens</h3></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="inserir.htm">Novo Personagem</a>
    </p>
    <table id="tabela" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Classe</th>
            <th colspan="3">Opções</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${lista}" var="p">
            <tr>
                <td>${p.id}</td>
                <td>${p.nome}</td>
                <td>${p.classe}</td>
            <form id="formAlterar${p.id}" method="get" action="alterar.htm">
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${p.id}" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formAlterar${p.id}').submit()">Alterar</a>
                </td>
            </form>
            <form id="formConsultar${p.id}" method="post" action="consultar.htm">
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${p.id}" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formConsultar${p.id}').submit()">Consultar</a>
                </td>
            </form>
            <form id="formExcluir${p.id}" method="post" action="excluir.htm">
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${p.id}" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formExcluir${p.id}').submit()">Excluir</a>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I have the javascript folder at the same level as WEB-INF. I think i pointed to the right place. but when i load the page, nothing happens, the table statys fixed, no sorting. Can it be related to the fact im using Spring MVC and the mapping makes it point to the wrong location? Heres my mapped method:

```
@RequestMapping("/personagem/index.htm")
public ModelAndView listar(@RequestParam(value = "mensagem", required = false) String mensagem) {
    ArrayList<Personagem> lista = getPersonagemService().listarTodos();
    return new ModelAndView("listar", "lista", lista);
}
```

Edit: The generated HTML code (it's a bit long, so i cut off the repeating part):

```
 <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/base.css"/> 
    <script src="/javascript/jquery-1.4.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/javascript/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <title>JSP Page</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabela").tableSorter();
        });
    </script> 
</head> 

<body>        
    <p> 
        <label><h3>Lista de Personagens</h3></label> 
    </p> 
    <p> 
        <a href="inserir.htm">Novo Personagem</a> 
    </p> 
    <table id="tabela" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
        <tr> 
            <th align="center">Nome</th> 
            <th align="center">Classe</th> 
            <th width="250" colspan="3">Opções</th> 
        </tr> 

            <tr> 
                <td width="150" align="center">Melys</td> 
                <td width="150" align="center">Priest</td> 
            <form id="formAlterar4" method="get" action="alterar.htm"> 
                <td align="center"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4" /> 
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formAlterar4').submit()">Alterar</a> 
                </td> 
            </form> 
            <form id="formConsultar4" method="post" action="consultar.htm"> 
                <td align="center"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4" /> 
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formConsultar4').submit()">Consultar</a> 
                </td> 
            </form> 
            <form id="formExcluir4" method="post" action="excluir.htm"> 
                <td align="center"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4" /> 
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formExcluir4').submit()">Excluir</a> 
                </td> 
            </form> 
        </tr>
```

Comment: Could we see the actual HTML that's generated? Is your page able to load the JS files?

Comment: I dont know, ill post the html

Comment: I just edited and added the HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you confirmed that the following resources are served properly? (e.g., they aren't 404, they are the correct content type, etc.)

- /css/base.css
- /javascript/jquery-1.4.3.js
- /javascript/jquery.tablesorter.js

If so, have you used something like the *Firefox Error Console* to ensure that there are no JavaScript errors in your code?

Also, why are you embedding forms in your table that appear to just link to a page with an id? In other words, why not just link to the page?

Comment: I checked with the error console and the only erro i get is '$ is not defined'

Comment: I changed the jQuery core reference to the remote version, and it stopped showing that error. The problems still remains because the tablesorter is local. I can't get the local path right.

Comment: So, it does sound like the three resources are not being served properly. This explains the error message you were getting and why it went away when you linked to a remote copy of jQuery. I'm not familiar with Spring MVC, so you may want to consult the documentation for serving static resources.